# Spring CacheEvict for Map

Tags: spring, memcached

I have the below method for caching

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = { "timeCache" })
    public Map<String, RechargeMatrix> getValues() {
         .....
    }
```

it has 58 values and it is caching successfully.
Now i want to evict a value in this cache. which

```
    @Override
    @CacheEvict(value = "timeCache", key = "#key")
    public void clearCache(String key) {
        LOG.debug("Clearing cache"); 
    }
```

the above code is not clearing the cache value.. I feel like i have to give entry key value for evicting a particular value.  but say clearCache("12345"); will not work as it is looking for string value instead of key value..
but dont no how to give in the #key .. 
any clue ?

```
thanks in advance
```

Comment: Fix the formatting please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is to clear and immediately re-cache your **timeCache** e.g. your **clearCache** method should be modified as shown below:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "timeCache", allEntries = true, beforeInvocation = true)
@Cacheable("timeCache")
public Map<String, RechargeMatrix> clearAndRecache() {
    // retrieve your timeCache values as in getValues() method
}
```

You can check this out in a sample project [here](https://github.com/sixhours-team/spring-boot-memcached-demo-java). This example is based on [Memcached Spring Boot library](https://github.com/sixhours-team/memcached-spring-boot).

**UPDATE:**

In case you need **key** parameter as in **clearCache(String key)** to delete data in your DB then your code should look something like this:

```
@CacheEvict(value = "timeCache", allEntries = true, beforeInvocation = true)
@Cacheable(value = "timeCache", key = "T(org.springframework.cache.interceptor.SimpleKey).EMPTY")
public Map<String, RechargeMatrix> deleteAndRecache(String key) {
    // 1. delete data in DB by key parameter 
    // 2. retrieve your timeCache values as in getValues() method and return it
}
```

The reason for all of this is that **getValues()** method will cache the data in memcached with the key having value `SimpleKey.EMPTY`. Hence the Map returned in this method should have the same key value.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. :)